# May an international student on F1-Visa accept money (cash rewards) in return of contributions made online?

Tags: united-states, cash, f1-student-visa, working-abroad, passive-income

I am an international student currently studying on F1-student-visa in united states.

There are many websites where I can contribute (for example, by adding questions/answers, writing articles etc.) and they pay money in return.

As what I know, it is not allowed to work in united states for students except for the on-campus jobs or under CPT, OPT.

Is contributing to online website considered as a "work" in US? Is it allowed legally?